# jQuery Click Event: Need two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid of elements and on click on every element, that element append the tittle in another div outside the grid (it's a simplified version of mi script).

The problem is, when I click on A element, runs good, the title append in a special div, but when I click on B element, the special div don't show the B title and when I click for twice, the special div shows the B title.

I search alot of this issues, with the double click on events, return false or event.stoppropagation, but doesen't work and I try to understand why, but I don't know what exactly which event are "assigned" to which element.

I'm working with a jquery.click looks like:

```
$('.grid div').click( function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $('h2').empty();

      var nombre = $(this).find('.nombre').text();

      $('h2').append(nombre);

      $('.info').toggleClass('undisplayed');

      $(this).toggleClass('active');

});
```

Every help should be nice :D

pd. Sorry for mi english

Comment: Why would you need to `preventDefault` on a div?

Comment: Also, `$('h2').empty()` and `$('h2').append(nombre)` could simply be `$('h2').text(nombre)`.

Comment: What does your html look like? The js looks functional

Comment: please give some HTML with this so we understand what A element and B element look like

Comment: the html looks like:

`<div class="grid"> 
   <div class="element"><h2>BLABLALBABa</h2></div>
   <div class="element"><h2>BLABLALBABa</h2></div>
   <div class="element"><h2>BLABLALBABa</h2></div>
</div>`

looks bad xD, but it's easy to undestand I guest

Comment: @isherwood Thanks! I try to find some ".replace" function in jQuery documentation... :,(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right the only changes would be the following:

```
$('.grid div').click( function(e) {
      var nombre = $(this).find('.nombre').text();
      $('h2').text(nombre);
      $('.info').toggleClass('undisplayed');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Yes, but I write an example with "h2" title, I append alot of thinks, one of these is a paragraph with br and if I use .text() the jquery pass the html like a string.

Answer (score 0):

exactly the event is functional... the only point is the "toggleClass"..

This is the reason why I need to click 2 times. 
The solution is really easy:

```
if( $('.info').hasClass('undisplayed') ) {
     $('.info').toggleClass('undisplayed');
}
```